# Rectangles in rectangles

Tags: code-golf, geometry, combinatorics, grid

This [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge will give you two positive integers `n` and `k` as inputs and have you count the number of rectangles with integer coordinates that can be drawn with vertices touching all four sides of the \$n \times k\$ rectangle $$
\{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq n, 0 \leq y \leq k\}.
$$
That is, there should be:

- at least one vertex with an \$x\$-coordinate of \$0\$,
- at least one vertex with an \$x\$-coordinate of \$n\$,
- at least one vertex with an \$y\$-coordinate of \$0\$, and
- at least one vertex with an \$y\$-coordinate of \$k\$.

#### Example

There are \$a(5,7) = 5\$ rectangles with integer coordinates touching all four sides of a \$5 \times 7\$ rectangle:

[image: Five examples of rectangles embedded in the 5 by 7 rectangle.]

#### Table

The lower triangle of the (symmetric) table of \$a(n,k)\$ for \$n,k \leq 12\$ is

```
n\k| 1  2  3  4  5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
---+----------------------------------------------
 1 | 1  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
 2 | 1  2  .  .  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
 3 | 1  1  5  .  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
 4 | 1  1  1  6  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
 5 | 1  1  1  3  9   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
 6 | 1  1  1  1  1  10   .   .   .   .   .   .
 7 | 1  1  1  1  5   1  13   .   .   .   .   .
 8 | 1  1  1  1  1   1   5  14   .   .   .   .
 9 | 1  1  1  1  1   5   1   1  17   .   .   .
10 | 1  1  1  1  1   3   1   3   1  18   .   .
11 | 1  1  1  1  1   1   5   1   5   5  21   .
12 | 1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   5   1   1  22
```

---

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code wins.

Comment: I get 9 distinct rectangles for `n=k=5`: [https://ibb.co/p49WdTc](https://ibb.co/p49WdTc). Am I missing something? I also have larger results on other (bigger) test cases, [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6vpKT0X8GQS8FQQcEITAKRKYwBRGZIbGMFBUskLhgZGqCKmIIFjdGVQaQMTbgwBaHmmGNIGSNIQwvsBkJJUwUjQ2wKUK0wMgL7FgA) is my result for the table.

Comment: @ovs—thanks for catching this! The table is updated now.

Comment: I took a shot at finding a combinatorial expression, but the best I got is: for \$k<n\$, the output is \$2C-3\$, where \$C\$ is the number of positive divisor pairs \$pq=n^2-k^2\$ with \$p\$ and \$q\$ having the same parity and both lying in the interval \$[n-k,n+k]\$. Unfortunately, the last interval condition seems to prevent a characterization in just terms of the factorization of \$n^2-k^2\$ without enumerating divisors. The condition corresponds to the inner rectangle fitting inside the outer one, rather than lying on its edges extended infinitely, a generalization that's easier to count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
LDI-*`¢O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx8VTVyvh0CL///@jTXUUTGMB)

**Commented**:

```python
          # implicit input: [n, k]
L         # for both values take the [1..x] range
          #   [[1,...,n], [1,...,k]]
 D        # duplicate this list
  I       # push the input [n,k]
   -      # subtract this from the ranges
          #   [[1-n,...,n-n], [1-k,...,k-k]]
          #  =[[-n+1,...,0], [-k+1,...,0]]
    *     # multiply with the ranges
          #   [[1*(-n+1),...,n*0], [1*(-k+1),...,k*0]]
     `    # push all lists of this list on the stack
      ¢   # count the occurences of each value of one list in the other
       O  # sum those counts
```

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>66</s> 59 bytes

```python
lambda n,k:sum(a%n*(n-a%n)==a/n*(k-a/n)for a in range(n*k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0xDsIwEAR7XnGNZV9IQA5dJP@E5lAwGJN1ZEKR1ztOhahWO9LszuvyTOiLd9fyluk2CqGNw@c7GVFoDLoa7Jyca4ldDfYpk1AAZcHjbtBE5rJD/KBtyV54OBDNOWAhTfr0SgFGq37Uypt6wrRL8U/C0daxDQ)

Each possible rectangle inside the \$n \times k\$-rectangle can be specified by two integers, \$0 \le a \lt n\$ and \$0 \le b \lt k\$:

[image]
[image]

To verify a rectangle given \$a\$ and \$b\$, it suffices to check if one angle is a right angle. To do this I take the dot product of \$\binom{b}{0}-\binom{0}{a}=\binom{-b}{a}\$ and \$\binom{k-b}{n}-\binom{0}{a}=\binom{k-b}{n-a}\$ to check whether the angle at \$\binom{0}{a}\$ is a right angle:

$$
  \langle \left( \begin{matrix}
-b \\
a \\
\end{matrix}\right), \left(\begin{matrix}
k-b \\
n-a \\
\end{matrix} \right) \rangle = 0 \\\Leftrightarrow a\cdot(n-a)-b\cdot(k-b)=0
\\\Leftrightarrow a\cdot(n-a)=b\cdot(k-b)
$$

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>63</s> 61 bytes

Saved 2 thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
s;a;f(n,k){for(s=a=n*k;a--;)s-=a%n*(n-a%n)!=a/n*(k-a/n);a=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTfb4IwEMff/StuJCSAbWZBVNJ1L8v@CvWhQdwMWWeABxPD386uMmk3wR/k6F3p99NeLy0p/UjTpim55FtPkdw/br8LrxRSqCDnklLul1RIVwWeouj8JyGfsZNTdD6XouR1s1MVfMmd8vzRcQT46A/ZYZ@lVbZhyzUIODICN6zmF2zYshMC4cNs1LFo8WPs1GbRZgSie9n4H4uWnMTxbXZ2yaKxyZmJuzx64HkvrNnIWjzuhxdDsOanJ3J45eQKrPn5eeW4B2aT67SeYDGYN2M3aX16BhJn4T20niA0dNDhLdxNRsy5NWFkwqkJYxPOTDg34cKECbFqZcXWeuycXvopiwCKNjFndXgPV4fkDd/YIWD3I@eX0Nddl0QhwTi6F/Qhh/FY@dDeZluWt7Jcy5RW5baqqy@quiLlQIGtl@rk@IW2Qm376/k7ti9wdOs57oa4G6CvgK1brhRuRBHICVQEN1oJka0tsh61bd38AA)

Port of [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213759/9481).

Answer (score 4):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>65</s> <s>64</s> <s>60</s> 51 bytes

```scala
n=>k=>0 to n*k-1 count(a=>a%n*(n-a%n)==a/n*(k-a/n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCsJADETv/YpQEDaVVutR2AWPHvwDL7G2ULdmFxtFkH77mgoemkMeMwMzY0MDpXC5tY3AiXqG9i0tX0c4xPjJQO9FA3R7OLKAdQskts5btwUJwIUva2jCk8WQdbTiwnCpQGtpo8KXCsRUVxJMvcPqTtHw3DXPLFz/dwHio9fCzjAaj7CG/Cw5ajLN7xcObDBTOaUv)

- -1 thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)!
- -4 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!
- -9 thanks to [Kjetil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64733/kjetil-s)!

Comment: You can save a byte by currying (`n=>k=>`)

Comment: You can use `1.to(n)` and `1.to(k)` for -2 bytes each.

Comment: Save 9 bytes with [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCsJADETv/YpQEDaVVutR2AWPHvwDL7G2ULdmFxtFkH77mgoemkMeMwMzY0MDpXC5tY3AiXqG9i0tX0c4xPjJQO9FA3R7OLKAdQskts5btwUJwIUva2jCk8WQdbTiwnCpQGtpo8KXCsRUVxJMvcPqTtHw3DXPLFz/dwHio9fCzjAaj7CG/Cw5ajLN7xcObDBTOaUv "Scala – Try It Online") I just translated the python answer from @ovs.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>63 58</s>  56 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ovs*

```javascript
(n,y=x=0)=>g=k=>(x=x||++y*k--&&n)&&(y*k==--x*(n-x))+g(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBTsJAEEDvfMWc2hk6u2FBRcWpJ77AozFm09JSFmeb0pgl4rfXenl5yUveyX/7SzV0/Wg01oepkQmVr5JkRVK2EqTEJOl2K4rrMhiTZUpZhrOLGJOWqCYRFS0Gmnbvjte84Tu@5wfe8iM/sVuxc@zWH7aJw95XR8TA8MngCaSEnwVAFfUSzwd7ji16@@V71P8080UgwCs0qDT/4Rlym5Md49s4dNoi2d7Xe61xQ2RPsVPMc6Ld4pemPw)

Comment: Since `y<k` and `x<n` the formula is slightly more readable if you write `k*y-y*y` and `n*x-x*x`.

Comment: I think `(n,y=x=0)=>g=k=> ... +g(k)` works for 56 bytes: https://tio.run/##FYzBTsJAEEDvfMWc2hk6u2FBRcWpJ77AozFm09JSFmeb0pgl4rfXenl5yUveyX/7SzV0/Wg01oepkQmVr5JkRVK2EqTEJOl2K4rrMhiTZUpZhrOLGJOWqCYRFS0Gmnbvjte84Tu@5wfe8iM/sVuxc@zWH7aJw95XR8TA8MngCaSEnwVAFfUSzwd7ji16@@V71P8080UgwCs0qDT/4Rlym5Md49s4dNoi2d7Xe61xQ2RPsVPMc6Ld4pemPw

Comment: @ovs It sure does. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＩΣＥθ№Ｅη×λ⁻ηλ×ι⁻θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oLmZ8B5AcUZeaVaDgnFpdoBJfmavgmFmgU6ig455cCRUGcDB2FkMzc1GKNHB0F38y80mKQSI6mpiZMPBMmDtSWqQkB1v//myqY/9cty0kEAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Calculates \$ x(n-x) \$ for \$ 0 \le x < n \$ and \$ y(n-y) \$ for \$ 0 \le y < k \$ and counts the number of times an integer appears in both lists, which corresponds to the parallelogram with coordinates \$ (x, 0), (0, y), (n - x, 0), (0, k - y) \$ having 90 degree angles:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input \$ n \$ and \$ k \$.

```
ＩΣ
```

Output the total sum of all matches found.

```
Ｅη×λ⁻ηλ
```

Calculate \$ y(n-y) \$ for \$ 0 \le y < k \$.

```
Ｅθ№...×ι⁻θι
```

Calculate \$ x(n-x) \$ for \$ 0 \le x < n \$ and count how many times each integer appears in the other list.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
r1×ḶċⱮ/S
```

A monadic Link accepting a pair of integers which yields the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/I8PD0hzu2Hel@tHGdfvD///@jTXXMYwE)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/I8PD0hzu2Hel@tHGdfvB/QyOdw/sSDrc/aloDRO7/AQ).

#### How?

```
r1×ḶċⱮ/S - Link [n,k]
r1       - ([n,k]) inclusive range to 1 = [[n,n-1,...,1],[k,k-1,...,1]]
   Ḷ     - lowered range ([n,k]) = [[0,1,...,n-1],[0,1,...,k-1]]
  ×      - multiply = [[n×0,(n-1)×1,...,1×(n-1)],[k×0,(k-1)×1,...,1×(k-1)]]
      /  - reduce by - i.e.: f(A=[n×0,(n-1)×1,...,1×(n-1)], B=[k×0,(k-1)×1,...,1×(k-1)])
     Ɱ   -   map with - i.e.: [f(A,v) for v in B]
    ċ    -     count occurrences (of v in A)
       S - sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 45 bytes

```
\d+
*
L$w`(_+) (_+)
$.`*$1=$.2*$'
m`^(.*)=\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPzPZWikxeWjUp6gp82loqehoqairqmjoqdmC@MoADlcfglc@jEp2gpArB@vquGe8B/I4oJo1IjX1lQAEUD9CVoqhkCdRloq6ly5CXEaelqatjGGKv//AwA) Link includes test suite. Takes space-separated inputs. Explanation:

```
\d+
*
```

Convert the inputs to unary.

```
L$w`(_+) (_+)
```

Match all substrings that contain `_ _`. This corresponds to all pairs of \$ 0 \le x < n \$ and \$ 0 \le y < k \$ which are represented by the unmatched parts at the beginning and end of the string `` $` `` and `$'` respectively while \$ n - x \$ and \$ k - y \$ are represented by `$1` and `$2` respectively.

```
$.`*$1=$.2*$'
```

For each pair, list the (unary) products \$ x (n - x) \$ and \$ y (k - y) \$.

```
m`^(.*)=\1$
```

Count the number of times that they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/),<s>53</s> 47 bytes

```hs
a#b=sum[1|x<-[1..a],y<-[1..b],x*(a-x)==y*(b-y)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5yba4NDfasKbCRjfaUE8vMVanEsJKitWp0NJI1K3QtLWt1NJI0q3UjP2fm5iZp2CrkJtY4BuvUFBaElxS5JOnEK1RnJFfrpCoqa2tpKOkrQ3hJoG4CrZ2CjARFaBtmjWJEOMNjWJ1kmB2xv4HAA)

- Saved 6 thanks to @ovs

We use the expression `x/(b-y)==y/(a-x)` which is converted to `x*(a-x)==y*(b-y)` to avoid modulo checks.

The expression computes the ratio between sides(the second inverted) which has to be the same to be a valid rectangle.

Comment: You can use `sum` instead of `foldr1(+)`: https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5yba4NDfasKbCRjfaUE8vMVanEsJKitWp0NJI1K3QtLWt1NJI0q3UjP2fm5iZp2CrkJtY4BuvUFBaElxS5JOnEK1RnJFfrpCoqa2tpKOkrQ3hJoG4CrZ2CjARFaBtmjWJEOMNjWJ1kmB2xv4HAA

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), (`-p` `-Minteger`) 54 bytes

```perl
/ /;$_=grep$_%$'*($'-$_%$')==$_/$'*($`-$_/$'),1..$`*$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYhBCoAgEEX3ncLFhBVNMgtpER6hM@hmkCBSzPM3lYv/3uNnLqcVMcps4F0snMH3oKcBNLYanQNv2hOw1TjTskCYQItYtXarst9@E3VEH5@U65GuW/DMgvtxVY5cXg)
Using the same formula, and range product as ovs except the range starts from 1

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 72 bytes

```forth
: f 0e over 0 do dup 0 do
2dup i - i * swap j - j * = s>f f- loop loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3NDsIgEITvPMV31mCKvdnYdzGW1RITCKA@Pi542J2fZGYk5vq0D@nQ2gVh8sSPz0xske2dBjHnznas3oHyvSWCiqDiSlkFsbxiTP@3aFH1pRpwM64X7bjjYOqhKuiSrIWZU1ZrxO55oFlGuP0A)

Yet another port of [ovs's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213759/78410), except that it uses nested loops. Direct loop counters are much cheaper when multiple copies are needed.

Takes `n k` from the main stack and returns the count via the FP stack.

```forth
: f ( n k -- f:cnt )
  0e               \ setup the initial count
  over 0 do        \ outer loop (j): 0 to n-1
    dup 0 do       \ inner loop (i): 0 to k-1
      2dup         \ ( n k n k )
      i - i * swap \ ( n k i*[k-i] n )
      j - j * =    \ ( n k i*[k-i]==j*[n-j] ) Forth boolean is 0/-1
      s>f f-       \ increment count if equal
    loop
  loop
;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 75 bytes

```java
n->k->{int r=0,a=n*k;for(;a-->0;)if(a%n*(n-a%n)==a/n*(k-a/n))r++;return r;}
```

Port of [*@ovs*' Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213759/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZExb8IwEIV3fsXJUiUb4xSQOhTjdKvUoRNj6eBCghyHS@Q4SIjmt6cOBAbUVJ3u7Od7@u450wctsq1tN7muKnjXBk8jgMprbzaQBTWqvcmjtMaNNwVGr32zfEOf7BI3@d@jvoljSEG1KGIr4pNBD05NJ1rh2Mq0cFRqIeKpZCal@gHHFEUoTCn9GA5WhMKY41y6xNcOwcmmlaPAW9ZfeeDtsQ@F2cI@rEJX3hncfXyCZt1aAKtj5ZN9VNQ@KoPkKcH12n4TJs9yx9BRoZpKwKWazUPhnJ3F36aBRC4pE@0pxs8vs8WcceThtve7H8iRDitECMEJJ@Lm@TRjd2C2A7MXMBvATkNk1AYeQhYdC7cB6bbj8JZXM4DLz6SRLsv8SJH1jb1Z/J2Fu2bhLlk0A5TnODqxGTXtDw)